# Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:]

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a table view and inside a custom UItableviewCell I am using collection view and I also create a custom collectionview cell. After setting all the basic functionalities of collection view in TableViewCell, When run the app I got the crash with reason:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (>)'

I tried to search more for it but can't find any direction

Here is my code snippet:
1. In TableViewcell awakeFrom Nib:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //  self.collectionView_Files.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MediaCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MediaCollectionCell")
   self.collectionView_Files.registerClass(MediaCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MediaCollectionCell")
}
```

CollectionView methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrFolderData.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let simpleTableIdentifier = "MediaCollectionCell"




    var cell: MediaCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionCell
    cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(simpleTableIdentifier, owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! (MediaCollectionCell)

    let dict = arrFolderData[indexPath.row]

    if(dict["file_type"] as! String == "0") { /// Means image
    cell.imgView_Item.image = UIImage(named: "images_41")
        cell.btn_ViewImage.hidden = false
        cell.btn_PlayVideo.hidden = true
    } else if (dict["file_type"] as! String == "1") { /// Means video
        cell.btn_ViewImage.hidden = true
        cell.btn_PlayVideo.hidden = false
        cell.imgView_Item.image = UIImage(named: "video_thumb_icon")
    }

    //   cell.backgroundColor = arrFolderData[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Collection view at row \(collectionView.tag) selected index path \(indexPath)")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{


    let length = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-15)/2
    return CGSizeMake(length,length);
}
```

Comment: remove this line:  `cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(simpleTableIdentifier, owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! (MediaCollectionCell)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I use custom collection cell....Now I removed that line....this time no crash, but no data showing in cell, no cell is displaying......can you suggest me another approach....?

Comment: For this crash I change tableCell and collectionCell. I removed the xib of both cells and add these cells in storyboard tableView.After that It was works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the post, I was working in tablecell xib file and try to do as I need, however once I change my approach and I create tableview cell into the UITableView inside the storyboard and update all the outlets and then run the app. The app was working fine....all the outlets in collection view cell are dynamically created with taking reference from their static variables.