# How to add UITableView inside UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used a xib for a custom collection view cell.
My application's first page is a list of some events, and the second page is event details (also in a table view). Now I show all list detail in detail page like on left-right swipe. How can I do this?

```
CollectionCell *cell = (CollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.dataArr = collectionData;
return cell;
```

Comment: Where is your code that you add tableview data and inside collectionview ? and what you try ?

Comment: Please don't use Xib, use storyboard cell instead of Xib. And please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347504/assertion-failure-in-uicollectionview-createpreparedcellforitematindexpathwi

Comment: @GouravJoshi my whole project in Xib